# Authentication without authorization on Tomcat 7

Tags: sql, authentication, tomcat, jdbcrealm

I have an annoying error which I can't solve for quite a while. I recently was introduced to container-based security and try to implement it. I have configure the realm as following:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
debug="99" 
driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/identify" 
connectionName="adm" connectionPassword="pw" 
userTable="users" userNameCol="login" 
userCredCol="password" 
allRolesMode="authOnly" /> 
</Realm>
```

Unfortunately I can't login with this. The log error messages are:

```
SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
    java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
    for the right syntax to use near 'null WHERE login = 'user1'' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2994)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1030)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getRoles(JDBCRealm.java:640)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:430)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:146)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:180)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:282)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Please notice the '' around the user name... Is this correct?

As you see I also use `allRolesMode="authOnly"`, because I don't need this functionality and moreover the database doesn't have and won't ever have an additional column for user roles (it is quite pointless if won't use it than every user will have the same value in this column - big waste of recourses.).

The server is Tomcat 7.0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `userRoleTable` and `roleNameCol` properties in case of `allRolesMode="authOnly"` too. Without them the SQL query will contain the String `null` (as you can see in the message of the exception). The value of `userRoleTable` could be the same as the value of `userTable`, and `roleNameCol` also could be same as `userNameCol`.

A simple workaround is creating an SQL view which emulates the `roles` table:

```
CREATE VIEW roles (username, role)
AS SELECT username, 'user' FROM users;
```

And a solution:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
    driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test" 
    connectionName="..." connectionPassword="..." 
    userTable="users" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password" 
    userRoleTable="users" roleNameCol="username"
/>
```

(Surprisingly it works without any `allRolesMode`.)

The required `web.xml` snippets:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected zone</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/prot/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
     <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

(Note: Lets say you have 1 million users, a new attribute in the `users` table with one million `user\0` string would cost only around 5 megabytes. I agree with that this is not a beautiful solution but it's not intolerable big nowadays.)

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to convince db admin to add this user role column after all, but if my negotiation don't work I'll try your approach. However it is dumb really that tomcat has such a limitation :/ I mean - some times you may not have any influence on the db construction and then you are screwed :/ Simple feature = big problems...

Comment: The "And a solution" works without any database schema modification and there are some other approaches: writing a custom `JDBCRealm` (Tomcat is opensource, so you can modify the existing one), implementing a custom `Valve` which add a role to the user's principal. So, it's not impossible but needs some work :)

Answer (score 0):

I have `Tomcat 7.0.27.0` with `JDK 1.6`

I am using tomcat only for Authentication and `not for authorization`

Following is the setup

context.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"  
       connectionName="login"  
       connectionPassword="password"    
       connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:authdb"    
       driverName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"        
       userTable="appusers"  
       userNameCol="username"              
       userCredCol="password"  
       allRolesMode="authOnly"/>
```

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>  
    <web-resource-collection>  
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>  
        <url-pattern>/modules/*</url-pattern>  
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>  
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>    
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>     
<!--
security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
security-role>
-->
```

I got it working by removing `<security-role>` block from web.xml  &
putting `auth-contraint` with role-name as `*`

If you remove `auth-contraint` block from `security-contraint` then web context authentication itself will not be invoked !!